# How to dynamically align a variable of a struct?

Tags: c, caching, memory-alignment

I have a struct that has many variables and I need to align some of the variables in the middle of the struct dynamically. For example I have the following struct and I want to align x5 into a cacheline by using posix_memalign or whatever. Is it possible?

```
struct many_vars {
    uint32_t x1;
    uint32_t x2;

    uint64_t x3;
    uint64_t x4;

    // ... 

    uint64_t x5;
    uint64_t x6;

    // ... 

    uint64_t x7;
    uint64_t x8;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think so. You should be able to do this:

```
typedef struct my_struct_optional_name {
    uint32_t ui32_1;
    uint32_t ui32_2;
    char char_1;
    // compiler inserts padding unless #pragma pack is in effect
    uint64_t ui64_1;
} my_struct_t;
my_struct_t *my_struct = aligned_alloc(64, sizeof(my_struct_t));
```

Answer (score 0):

The compilers normally insert padding between structure fields to get the best alignment possible.  This includes cache line alignment and other things.  There are two strong reasons for your attempt not being ok in this field.

- Your alignment is probably not considering the alignment being done by the compiler, and you'll fight with it.  For this to work you first have to disable all the alignment optimisations done by the compiler.  So your code and the compiler don't fight.
- The compiler will probably make better alignments than you.  It's designed based on a more thorough study of the alignment problem and probably you'll not consider cases in where the alignment can be much better organised.  It can handle hundreds of alternatives and select the best when you are not capable of consider such a number of cases.  In my opinion it's better to let the compiler do this phase of program design.  Just in case you want to test your skils and lose your fight with the compiler, there is no recommendation you can be given.  For this to work (at least better than the compiler does) you have to be very proficient at memory alignment.  And compiler writers are.